# Angular 4 Add a component as a background in another component

Tags: angular

I need to add a component as a background to another component. I know how to set the background in a component, but I have one component which will just be a div with a background with logic to decide what to display, and I need to set this as a  background of another component.

Is this possible? I have included the background component inside of the parent, but it pushes everything down instead of showing behind it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could propably use Angular's transclusion - your parent component would need to contain ng-content directive.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content

Comment: This is a good solution if I just wanted the background. However I have elements that should go over the background which shouldn't change. From what I've read in this article, whatever I add using transclusion will still just push the current contents down, instead of appearing behind them.